# How to parse quotes correctly?

Tags: python, sql, antlr

I'm using ANTLR with Presto grammar in order to parse SQL queries. This is the definition of the string I'm using:

```
STRING
    : '\'' ( ('\\' '\'') | ~'\'' | '\'\'' )* '\''
    ;
```

However, when I have a query like this:

```
select replace(name,'\'','')
FROM table1;
```

it mess things up as it parses : '\'',' as one string.

When I used the following rule instead:

```
STRING
    : '\'' ( ('\\' '\'') | ~'\'')* '\''
    ;
```

I didn't parse correctly queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where col1 = 'nir''s'
```

which of course is a legal query.

Any idea how can I catch both?

Thanks,
Nir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to support `\'`, you should not only negate the single quote, but also negate the backslash.

Something like this:

```
STRING
    : '\'' ( '\\' '\''   // match \'
           | ~[\\']      // match anything other than \ and '
           | '\'\''      // match ''
           )* 
      '\''
    ;
```

And to account for different escaped characters, do this:

```
STRING
    : '\'' ( '\\' ~[\r\n] // match \ followed by any char other than a line break
           | ~[\\']       // match anything other than \ and '
           | '\'\''       // match ''
           )* 
      '\''
    ;
```

Comment: My suggestion wil tokenise `'\''` as one token and `'nir''s'` is one token. This is not what you want? If so, please update your question and clearly indicate what token you're expecting.

Comment: @Nir99 Your problem is that your `\` is eaten up by `'\''` and thus not seen as part of an escaped quote. That's why `'\'',''` is lexed as a single string. Bart's suggestion fixes that and will cause `'\'',''` to be lexed as two strings (and a comma and a space), which is what you want.

Comment: @brat, I'm sorry, I didn't understand your answer at first reading. But this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Comment: umm, in fact I'm still having an issue with different queries with regex. For example, I'm failing to parse correctly the following query because I'm not parsing the string correctly: 
select * 
from table1
where REGEXP_MATCH(col1, r'^\d{8}$')

Comment: also tried to update the rule but no luck: 
    : '\'' ( '\\' '\''   // match \'
           | '\\' 'd'
           | ~[\\']      // match anything other than \ and '
           | '\'\''      // match ''
           )*
      '\''
    ;

Comment: yes, now it works for the other cases as well. Thanks again!

Comment: I was using the string definition as @BartKiers suggested: 
`STRING
    : '\'' ( '\\' ~[\r\n] // match \ followed by any char other than a line break
           | ~[\\']       // match anything other than \ and '
           | '\'\''       // match ''
           )*
      '\''
    ;
`
However, when I have the following query: 
select NULLIF(REPLACE(v1,'\',''),'')
      from table1 
The string that I'm getting is: 
',''),'

Can I fix it to get the different strings: 
1 = '\' 
2 = '' 
3=''

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The comment boxes are not well suited for asking question, so I suggest you create a new question instead.